# PySpark: The system cannot find the path specified. (From PyCharm)

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am able to start pyspark from my command prompt. But the program written in Pycharm fails with the following error:

```
C:\Dev\Python\python.exe C:/Dev/programs/may/test_sparky.py
The system cannot find the path specified.
*.. <And the program hangs here forever ..*
```

I have installed pyspark using pip.

Tried Spark 3.0.0 Winutils 3.0.0 ,

Then now I have downgraded to:

**spark version 3.0.1.**

**winuitls.exe version 2.7.1**

My System Env Variables appear to be perfect because I can **launch pyspark from command prompt.**

```
JAVA_HOME:C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_331
SPARK_HOME:C:\Users\may\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pyspark
HADOOP_HOME:C:\Dev\Hadoop
```

%PATH%:

```
....C:\Dev\Python;C:\Dev\Python\Scripts;
C:\Users\may\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pyspark\bin;
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_331\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\bin;
C:\Dev\Hadoop\bin ....
```

Spark Version

```
C:\Dev>pyspark --version
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 3.0.1
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.12.10, Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, 1.8.0_331
Branch HEAD
Compiled by user ubuntu on 2020-08-28T07:36:48Z
Revision 2b147c4cd50da32fe2b4167f97c8142102a0510d
Url https://gitbox.apache.org/repos/asf/spark.git
Type --help for more information.
```

Java Version

```
C:\Dev>java -version
java version "1.8.0_331"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_331-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.331-b09, mixed mode)
```

Comment: have you checked if the paths are added in pycharm as well?

Comment: The executable path in PyCharm should ideally be `spark-submit`, **not** `python.exe` (use Run configuration to change)

Comment: Thanks samkart and @OneCricketeer. Yes adding path to pycharm configuration should have worked. But while troubleshooting I realised, I installed full Spark and point ed SPARK_HOME to the extracted location, rather than pointing to pip installed Site-package location.  And it worked without making changes to pycharm.

Answer (score 1):

Installing spark from apache.org and pointing SPARK_HOME to extracted location worked.